# Three20 TTTableViewController and searchViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I am trying to implement adding recipients to TTMessageController based on the example from TTCatalog. 
Everything works fine until I enter search controller - I can search and get results, but nothing happens when I select items. I tried to set delegates, but none works.

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    TTTableViewController* searchController = [[TTTableViewController alloc] init];
    searchController.dataSource = [[FriendsDataSource alloc] initWithApi:self.appDelegate.api];
    searchController.variableHeightRows=YES;
    self.searchViewController = searchController;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
}
```

In TTCatalog, items in search have an URL directing to google - that's not very helpful ;)

Comment: I was just going to post the exactly same question!

Comment: I guess you have already implemented `- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    [_delegate searchTestController:self didSelectObject:object];
}` right?

Comment: I was missing delegate set....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer :)

One line was missing from the code above. I had a feeling I should set the delegate, but didn't know where:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    TTTableViewController* searchController = [[TTTableViewController alloc] init];
    searchController.dataSource = [[FriendsDataSource alloc] initWithApi:self.appDelegate.api];
    self.searchViewController = searchController;
    _searchController.searchResultsTableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
}
```

Then it as enough to add this to allow variable heights:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    id<TTTableViewDataSource> dataSource = (id<TTTableViewDataSource>)tableView.dataSource;

    id object = [dataSource tableView:tableView objectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Class cls = [dataSource tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
    return [cls tableView:tableView rowHeightForObject:object];
}
```

And this to handle selection:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TTTableImageItemCell *cell = (TTTableImageItemCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    TTTableImageItem *object = [cell object];
    [_delegate MessageAddRecipient:self didSelectObject:object];
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there. Nice way doing it by setting the `UITableViewDelegate`. However, I was expecting Three20 to be little more intelligent and do this for you somehow. Anyway, you solved my problem. Thanks a lot!